# How to find how many times a string appears in CSV file

Tags: python, loops, csv

I need to know how many times a string appears in a CSV file. The code I have is not giving me the right number.

```
import csv
import re
def main():

    print('Here is the File Information.')
    print('_' * 29)
    infile = open('employee_payroll.csv', 'r').read()



    count = 0
    string = 'Board of Regents'
    for string in infile:
        count+= 1
```

Comment: Please describe with more details... **"not giving me the right number"**... Are you far from the right one ?

Comment: `'Board of Regents'` isn't actually being used anywhere, as the name `string` is immediately replaced by the loop variable; you're literally just counting the number of lines in the file. Also, note that Python has a `csv` library that would probably help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should help solve the issue you are having. You may find that you need to experiment with the data. Does the data have `\n` characters? Is it comma, tab delimited? Irrespective the below code should help you on your way.

```
count = 0
with open(file) as  f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split('with_my_delimiter'):
            if word == 'my_word':
                count = count + 1
```

Comment: SO doesn't use GitHub-flavoured Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [.count()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count) function

```
csv = """
Foo, 20, Berlin
Bar, 23, Paris
Max, 44, New York
Foo, 74, Sydney
"""

print csv.count('Foo')
```

Comment: What `'FooFooFooFootbool'.count('Foo')`? This only counts substrings you should point out...

Answer (score 0):

csv will create an list of a list representing tabular data of the file.  search each list for the string match.  use a regular expression findall if you want to pattern match.

```
import csv

def search_csv(filename, phrase):
    count=0
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if phrase in row:
                print(row)
               count+=1
    return count

count=search_csv("c:\\users\yourname.domain\yourfile.csv","123.0")
print("count ={}".format(count))
```

output:

```
count =3
```